# How do I identify and resolve memory leaks in WPF's BeginInvoke()?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, begininvoke

I'm working a windows .Net C# WPF application.
The application displays video frames in addition to displaying some additional analytic data in a canvas.

The app is processing a frame rate of about 15 frames per second.
Processing is completed on separate thread. The processing thread sends callbacks when analysis is completed and the display is to be updated.

I've noticed some significant memory growth (leaks) as I run the application over a period of time. After running for a couple of hours, the application's memory footprint grows to a size of over 200MB.

In order to try to track these leaks, I'm using red-gate's ANTs Memory Profiler.
 Based on the results I've captured, it appears that my dispatcher.BeginInvoke() calls are the source of at least some of the leaks.

The dispatcher.BeginInvoke() is required as I am updating the UI from a different thread (one other than the UI thread.

**Here is a sample code block from the application:**

```
canvas.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke((Action)(() =>
{
   // Clear the previous points
   canvas.Children.Clear();
   SolidColorBrush pointBrush = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Cornsilk);
   foreach (var point in points)
   {
      Ellipse ellipse = new Ellipse()
      {
         Width = 4,
         Height = 4,
         Fill = pointBrush
      };

      canvas.Children.Add(ellipse);
      Canvas.SetLeft(ellipse, point.x * XScaleFactor);
      Canvas.SetTop(ellipse, point.y * YScaleFactor);
   }

   SolidColorBrush boundingBrush = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Bisque);
   Rectangle boundingBox = new Rectangle()
   {
      Width = width,
      Height = height,
      Stroke = boundingBrush,
      StrokeThickness = 1,
   };

   canvas.Children.Add(boundingBox);
   Canvas.SetLeft(boundingBox, xMin * mImageXScaleFactor);
   Canvas.SetTop(boundingBox, yMin * mImageYScaleFactor);
   }
}));
```

After a run with red-gate Memory Profiler, I see many instances of the Dispatcher() class which look like they leak around 64 bytes per instance. Keeping in mind that I'm processing 15ish frames per second, this adds up steadily. Is there something drawing-wise that's occurring within the anonymous function block which is preventing the overhead associated with each BeginInvoke() from getting freed up?

How do I figure out what is really going on here and how do I resolve this issue?

Thanks,
JohnB

Comment: Get one snapshot, get the second one, compare them and look at all new objects. See who holds these objects in memory. Ask if you have further questions :)

Comment: Ed.ward ::> It looks like this might not be as obvious to figure it out. As I examine the snapshots, I notice that I get an increased number of DispatcherOperation objects. It seems to be linear, in that the longer I run, the more I see. I assume that the DispatcherOperation object is associated with the control->BeginInvoke() call. Thoughts?

Comment: At first I would see when DispatcherOperation objects are created. And what roots holds them in memory. It can give a key to understanding how to release them. 
I'm not familiar with ANTS and can't give a tip how to see this information there, I use dotMemory from JetBrains.